# using f string and .format together

Tags: python

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
age= int(input("How old are you,{0}?" .format(name)))

print(age)

if age >= 22:
    print(f"Congratulations {name} , You're eligible to vote.")
else:
    print(f"Oops {name} ,We're are sorry but you can try again in {0} years." .format(22 - age))
```

The outcome is not minusing the .format command? can we not use both the functions into one line of code.

Answer (score 3):

The f string is evaluated to a `str` which has the `format` method, so yes, it will work. The trick is that you have to escape the brackets intended for the `format` method so that they resolve properly later.

```
>>> foo = "bar"
>>> f"foo {foo} 0 {{0}}".format("baz")
'foo bar 0 baz'
```

Notice that `{{0}}` resolves to `{0}` in the f string and then to the first formatted parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense at all, you can do everything with f-strings:

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
age = int(input(f"How old are you {name}? "))
print(age)
if age >= 22:
    print(f"Congratulations {name}, You're eligible to vote.")
else:
    print(f"Oops {name}, We're are sorry but you can try again in {22 - age} years.")
```

f-strings are now the best option. For more info see:
https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#abstract

Comment: While you're not wrong, per se, this does not actually answer the question and belongs in a comment instead.